# Convert Epoch Date to meaningful Javascript date

Tags: javascript, date, epoch

I am getting a string value `"/Date(1342709595000)/"`in the JSON. I am trying to extract the digits alone and convert the epoch date to meaning ful Javascript Date in the format mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss . I was able to achieve the first part of the question extracting the digits but couldnot convert it to date object human readable format as available in http://www.epochconverter.com/

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/QzKwE/3/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing you really need to do, they are already milliseconds since epoch and javascript dates take milliseconds since epoch.

http://jsfiddle.net/QzKwE/9/

```
var dateVal ="/Date(1342709595000)/";
var date = new Date(parseFloat(dateVal.substr(6)));
document.write( 
    (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
    date.getDate() + "/" +
    date.getFullYear() + " " +
    date.getHours() + ":" +
    date.getMinutes() + ":" +
    date.getSeconds()
);
```

​

Comment: Works fine. Could you please explain the second line of code.

Comment: @Ravi it takes the number from `"/Date(1342709595000)/"` and passes it to `new Date`. It's same as saying `new Date(1342709595000);`

Comment: THanks so much.. It makes more sense now